# How to use iPhone Camera in Burst Mode

Tags: iphone

In one of my project I have to use the iPhone Camera in "Burst Mode". How it could be done, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the `takePicture` method of `UIImagePickerController` with a delay of say 0.1 seconds for any number of times.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this and let you know the result.